# In a new ubuntu 18, Ping works very well, but wget and browser error?

Tags: networking, wget

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 which was installed just now.
I formatted the "/" part, but keep the "/home" part.

The computer had been Ubuntu 14.04 before the reinstallation.
The network wasn't right when Ubuntu 14.04 and still error now.

When I ping a domain, it works very well, but wget apt and browser can't work.

When adding a USB wireless card, the network is alright.
What should I do to find out the problem?

```
$ ping -c3 askubuntu.com

PING askubuntu.com (151.101.65.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=134 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=133 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=132 ms

--- askubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 132.458/133.681/134.628/1.000 ms
```

$ wget askubuntu.com

```
--2019-01-29 12:05:12--  http://askubuntu.com/
Resolving askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)... 151.101.65.69, 151.101.1.69, 151.101.193.69, ...
Connecting to askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)|151.101.65.69|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)|151.101.1.69|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)|151.101.193.69|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to askubuntu.com (askubuntu.com)|151.101.129.69|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

Here is the other information.

$ route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
```

$ ifconfig -a

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.199  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::9997:3ae3:6798:1ac8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:ea:01:28:99:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 141444  bytes 136582388 (136.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 79  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 82546  bytes 5792934 (5.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6524  bytes 984671 (984.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6524  bytes 984671 (984.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```